# Express the indefinite integral $\int\sin x^2~dx$ as a power series

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series, indefinite-integrals

What does this mean? I never saw this in my class/notes so I don't understand the conversion from integral to power series.

Also if the integral were defined from $0$ to $1$, what new steps do I add?

Comment: the idea is that, under suitable conditions ensuring convergence, the power series can be integrated term by term. there is a well-known series for $sin x$ hence you have a series for $sin x^2$

Comment: I see... my understanding came to this. use taylor to expand $sin(x)$ then replace all $x$ with $x^2$ on both sides of the expansion. you then multiply both sides by $dx$ and integrate... so the basics is "Maclaurian" to multiply by $dx$ to integrate all terms on the RHS and the LHS

Comment: if the integral is definite does the expansion only go up to the end point? and that is what is different?

Comment: your first comment is correct. re your second, there is no connection here between the limits of integration and how many terms of the expansion you should use, except perhaps from the point of view of a finite approximation. to get the exact result you always have to use all the terms of the MacClaurin series.

Comment: Im guessing that expressing it as a number series from say, 0 to 1, is to just apply the 0 and then 1 to all terms in the power series? add that up.  
or what is would the number series be expressed as for $\int_{0}^{1} sinx^2 dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int\sin x^2~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(x^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}+C$

$\therefore\int_0^1\sin x^2~dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}\right]_0^1$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}$